# Docker for golang application

Tags: docker, go

i've golang application which I want to build docker image for it
the application folder called `cloud-native-go` and the dockerfile is under the root project
Any idea what is wrong here ?

```
FROM golang:alpine3.7
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
RUN go-wrapper install    # "go install -v ./..."

#final stage
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /app
ENTRYPOINT ./app
LABEL Name=cloud-native-go Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 3000
```

**The error is :**

```
Step 5/12 : RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
 ---> Running in 70c2e00f332d
/bin/sh: go-wrapper: not found
```

i Build it with

`docker build -t cloud-native-go:1.0.0 .`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`go-wrapper` has been deprecated and removed from the images using `go` version 10 and above. See [here](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/pull/205).

If you are fine using `go v1.9` you can use the following image: `golang:1.9.6-alpine3.7`.

So your `Dockerfile` will be:

```
FROM golang:1.9.6-alpine3.7
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN go-wrapper download   # "go get -d -v ./..."
RUN go-wrapper install    # "go install -v ./..."

#final stage
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /app
ENTRYPOINT ./app
LABEL Name=cloud-native-go Version=0.0.1
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: Thanks and if I want to use the latest alpine , is there a way to use someting else instead go-wrapper to make it work?

Comment: You should either manually `go get` your dependencies yourself and then  `go install` or use a package manager like [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) or [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) to install the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM golang:alpine

# important!
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GOOS=linux
ENV GOARCH=amd64
ENV GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor
ENV APP_USER app
ENV APP_HOME /go/src/microservices

RUN mkdir /nameApp
ADD . /nameApp
WORKDIR /nameApp

//compile your project
RUN go mod vendor
RUN go build

//open the port 8000
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "/nameApp/nameApp" ]
```