# app would not be build after docker-compose up because go-wrapper would not be installed

Tags: docker, go

Hello I am Java developer, but i have golang microservice which I want to build docker image. I have anything changed but it would be not build any more.

This is Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache git bash

WORKDIR /go/src/mailman
COPY . .

RUN go-wrapper download
RUN go-wrapper install

CMD ["go-wrapper", "run"]
```

This is result after docker-compose up

```
Building mailman
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.8-alpine
.
.
.
Step 6/7 : RUN go-wrapper install
 ---> Running in c3c55bd70517
+ exec go install -v
github.com/streadway/amqp
github.com/BurntSushi/toml
gopkg.in/yaml.v2
gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/json
gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/scram
werdewelt/mailman/domain
gopkg.in/gomail.v2
gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson
gopkg.in/mgo.v2
github.com/jinzhu/configor
# github.com/jinzhu/configor
../../github.com/jinzhu/configor/utils.go:173: decoder.DisallowUnknownFields undefined (type *json.Decoder has no field or method DisallowUnknownFields)
ERROR: Service 'mailman' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I have already tried to upgade to golang:1.9.6-alpine3.7 how in this solution, but it not help:
[Docker for golang application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707946/docker-for-golang-application/50708472)

Please help!

Comment: Can you add some more information on what the error message was when you used the solution you linked? Also, are the modules you are using vendored into your source code?

Comment: If 1.8-alpine means go version 1.8, that's a very old version of go. Use a recent version, like 1.14

Comment: @Simon I have the same error mesage when i used linked solution. I have tryed to change go version to this: golang:1.9.6-alpine3.7

Comment: DisallowUnknownFields was added after 1.10

Comment: @BurakSerdar it means i must anyway upgrade to min 1.10? i've tryed this but go-wrapper was in  1.10 deprecated.  after RUN go-wrapper download i have bocome error: ERROR: Service 'mailman' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper download' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: I suggest you change your build to use go modules.

Comment: @BurakSerdar can you help me with build. I have any ideas how to use go modules.

Comment: It should be as simple as using a recent go version and running `go install`, assuming you're running this in the directory containing your main package, because go modules will download modules as they are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution.
Thanks [Burak Serdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11923999/burak-serdar)

I have go to 1.14 upgraded. This is my upgraded Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.14-alpine3.11

RUN apk add --no-cache git bash

WORKDIR /go/src/mailman
COPY . .

RUN go get
RUN go install

CMD ["go", "run", "mailman.go"]
```